# Jquery Validate word space

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-validate

First of all please forgive my poor English.
I want to validate when input more than 15 word without space.Because if input without space,the table won't auto break line.I mean my table show info like this :

```
  <td><%= e[i].getDescription %></td>
```

The min size of that description is 50 and max is 200.If they only input

```
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA..."
```

it will make my template broke :(
So I want to ask if there is a validate method to prevent it .
Thanks

Comment: add the following css: [`word-wrap:break-work`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

Comment: **Quote OP:** _"I want to validate when input more than 15 word without space"_  ~ If there are no spaces, how would you know how many words?

Comment: @Pete: ah Thanks you,it working now.
Sparky: I see, because the teacher told me that I should use that method,but can't figure it out.

Comment: My point is that it makes no sense.  Without spaces, it becomes **one** long word, not 15... so how would you know where the spaces belong?  `sohowwouldyouknowwherethespacesbelong?`

Comment: I see, please forgive my poor knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"So I want to ask if there is a validate method to prevent it."*

No, jQuery Validate plugin does not have a built-in method that counts words, but you can write one using [the `addMethod` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

However, AFAIK, there is no simple method that can figure out the number of words when there are no spaces... then you have nothing but one long word.  Unless you iterate over each letter and its surrounding letters until you get a match against a dictionary.  This endeavor will quickly become more complex than practical, as a string of letters *could possibly* be broken into more than one set of words... then you'd need a routine that can figure out context to judge the most likely sentence.  All this just to keep a table layout from breaking?

Anyway, since all you really want to do is preserve the integrity of the layout, use CSS on the element to wrap and break long strings.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Comment: I see, thanks you very much , I will keep it in mind :D.

Comment: @NguyenTrongNhan, I've directly answered your question.  Please "accept" my answer.